# Nginx Ingress Controller Returns 404 Kubernetes

Tags: docker, nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I am trying to create an ingress controller that points to a service that I have exposed via NodePort.

Here is the yaml file for the ingress controller (taken from https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/):

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: hello-world.info
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: appName
          servicePort: 80
```

I can connect directly to the node port and the frontend is displayed.

Please note that I am doing this because the frontend app is unable to connect to other deployments that I have created and I read that an ingress controller would be able to solve the issue. Will I still have to add an Nginx reverse proxy? If so how would I do that? I have tried adding this to the nginx config file but with no success.

```
location /middleware/ {
      proxy_pass http://middleware/;
   }
```

Comment: What is the URL you are getting 404 from?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I get the 404 from the minikube ip address. I get such url when running `kubectl get ingress`

Comment: Have you updated your `hosts` file? `hello-world.info` won't work since it's won't be resolved by the host.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I decided to skip using the actual name and just go straight to the ip. Could that be the issue?

Comment: Yeap. In case of IP you need to a catch all Ingress. Adding my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use a proper hostname to reach the route defined in the `Ingress` object. Either update your `/etc/hosts` file or use `curl -H "hello-world.info" localhost` type command. Alternatively, you can delete the `host` mapping and redirect all traffic to one default service.

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: appName
          servicePort: 80
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much! However I am still having trouble allowing this pod to access other pods. Would I still need to use a Nginx reverse proxy? How would I do this? Thanks.

EDIT: For reference I have `http://middleware` and other references like that in my code. Thanks for the help. I am still learning K8s.

Comment: You need to expose other pods as services and use the service for communication. Just like in this example, ingress controller is able to talk to `appName` service. Expose `middleware` as a Service object and `http://middleware` would work. HTH

Comment: Hmm. I have a middleware service already set up and can curl (`curl http://middleware`) it from another pod. But when I have the service name in the website it says error name not resolved

Comment: I have read that it is because this code is being executed in the browser and thus would not be able to access the services. Is this correct? How would I fix this?

Comment: If you need to access the service from outside, for example from your browser, you need to add another Ingress route. You can create another Ingress object with either path or host. Check this example: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#the-ingress-resource . Once you have the path route, you can access the service on that path for example http://localhost/middleware . Don't forget to add the re-write annotation.

Comment: Hmm. I don't want to give the user access to the middleware/other components that I have written. Is is possible to do it another way? That way only the frontend pod is able to contact them?

Comment: If the front-end pod is a single-page application calling backend then no. The backend has to be available. However, if front-end pod is a backend service (nodejs/java/python/go...) then it can access the service on the cluster using ClusterIP.

Comment: Your ingress controller is actually a reverse proxy. It compiles all Ingress objects and creates the routes for you.